# Azure API Management gateway transformation policy

Tags: azure, policy, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

Is it possible to convert JSON response objects (Null,int etc) to type string by applying transformation policy? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody policy. This policy will let you to write code to set body. You need to convert body to JSObject, then set properties as you request and then set JSObject back to body and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Sheethal , will let you know once implemented. Cheers

Comment: Hi Sheethal ,Thank you , we have done that successfully . Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use either C# or liquid templates to do the transformation. It is easier to maintain using liquid templates as you create a template document to map fields, or create different document. This enables us to easily see the mapping.  A quick snippet should look like:

```
 <set-body template="liquid">
{

  "firstName": "{{body.contact.name}}",
  "address": "{{body.addressInfo.street}}"
 ...

}
</set-body>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. This was already sorted in 2018 using transformation policy and rewriting to the required format in API Management gateway with C#